# Get Count of Leaf Nodes

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have found a solution from

[LINK](http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/tech-resources/articles/hierarchical-data.html)

to get all the Leaf Nodes
We can find all the leaf nodes in our tree (those with no children) by using a LEFT JOIN query:

```
SELECT t1.name FROM
category AS t1 LEFT JOIN category as t2
ON t1.category_id = t2.parent
WHERE t2.category_id IS NULL;
```

I want to get the parent most Parent ID with all these child elements. Like in above case, Electronics is the parent most parent id. How could I do that with this query? Can I use any group by clause to do this?

Here is my SQLFIDDLE LINK : [Click Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d03997/1)

Its giving all the subcategories with no childs further but I want their top most parent id as well so that I can calculate the number of Subcategories(who has no more child elements) of a parent element.

Comment: Can you supply sample data and desired results?  To get the most results per name, using aggregate functions is the way to go.  To traverse the tree of child-to-parent categories, that could be more difficult.

Comment: Please click on the LINK in my question to see the results. I am able to get the subcategories with no children but not able to find the top most parent element of each subcategory using this query.